# Jtable, jQuery selectionchange is not working

Tags: jquery, jtable, jquery-jtable

I am trying to select values in one table so that according to the selected value, the values in the other table changes. I am trying to achieve this using jQuery jTable. I have got the values in both the table but when I select a value in table 1, the values in the table 2 remains the same,
Here my table 1 is #selecteventtype and table 2 is selecteventcode.
My jQuery code for the selectionchanged is

```
  selectionChanged: function () {
                      var $selectedRows = $('#selecteventtype').jtable('selectedRows');
                      if ($selectedRows.length > 0) {
                          $selectedRows.each(function () {
                              var record = $(this).data('record');
                              selectedtype = record.irs_type;
                              $('#selecteventcode').jtable('load', irs_type:selectedtype );
                            console.log(selectedtype)
                          });
                      }
                  },
```

Can someone help me with this

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
$('#selecteventcode').jtable('load', {irs_type:selectedtype} );
```